# How to override an inherited control's event without having access to it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I'm working on a project where I'm actually using inherited controls with some automated behaviour so I don't need to re-do all the job. The controls are being inherited from DevExpress controls and I've got access to the inherited controls.

I reached a point where an event was being raised and subscribing to my own method was showing no results because the inherited control executed its own code.

Inherited control:

```
private void BinaryGridView_InvalidRowException(object sender, InvalidRowExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.ExceptionMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ExceptionMode.NoAction;
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(e.ErrorText, "Atención", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Own method in my form:

```
grwWhatever.InvalidRowException += (s, e) => { e.ExceptionMode = ExceptionMode.NoAction; };
```

According to the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ExceptionMode.enum), I was trying to hide any message box and of course, as my inherited control source says, it was showing that message box.

So, reaching that point I guess had two options:

1.- Inheriting from that inherited control, changing the `private` to `protected virtual` and overriding that behaviour. This wasn't a choice since, for reasons I couldn't explain here **I must use uniquely those inherited controls**.

2.- Changing the `private` to `public`, so I could unsubscribe and subscribe again, afterwards:

```
grwWhatever.InvalidRowException -= grwWhatever.BinaryGridView_InvalidRowException;
grwWhatever.InvalidRowException += (s, e) => { e.ExceptionMode = ExceptionMode.NoAction; };
```

This 2nd option is actually working fine but... let's guess none of them are doable. Changing the content of the inherited control's event is not a possibility. Leaving a part the inherited control's usage design... **Which would be the best way to proceed**? Could it be done using `Reflection`?

Comment: `BinaryGridView_InvalidRowException` is only subscribed event then you can assign `grwWhatever.InvalidRowException` to `null`. In that case, no need to change the accessor type to `public`.

Comment: if `NoAction` value for `ExceptionMode`, for you always means show no message box, then just go to the *Inherited control* and add the if statement before the message box:  `if (e.ExceptionMode==ExceptionMode.NoAction)`.

Comment: Also in the *inherited control*, if possible, it's better to overrode `OnInvalidRowException` for extension, rather than having an event handler.

Comment: @RezaAghaei sorry, I didn't explain that changing the **content** of the inherited control's event is not a possibility. The idea is just changing the behaviour on the desired form/place

Comment: If `BinaryGridView_InvalidRowException` is an event handler which is subscribed into the event in the inherited control and you cannot change the inherited control code, then You can not stop it from working.

Comment: Both of your suggested solutions are also relying on changing the access modifier of the event handler in inherited control. So none of them are applicable.

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei, I was curious if it could be painfully done through Reflection or so as well.

Comment: Yes there is solution using reflection. I'll post an example using `Form` class and its `Load` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution should be changing the code in the base class. But since you have mentioned you don't have access to change the code of base class, and a solution using reflection is also acceptable, here I will share an example using reflection, for *learning purpose*.

**Remove private event handler subscription from base class**

I assume I have a base class called `MyBaseForm` and you have handled `Load` event using `MyBaseForm_Load` private method in the base class.

In this example, in a derived class `MyDerivedForm`  which is derived from base class, I use some reflection code to remove the `MyBaseForm_Load` event subscription and instead, I handle the event using a new handler in the derived class `MyDerivedForm_Load`.

The expected behavior:

- Before removing the event handler, you will see two message boxes
- After removing the event handler using `eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler`, you will see just a single message box, from the derived class event handler.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyBaseForm : Form
{
    public MyBaseForm()
    {
        this.Load += MyBaseForm_Load;
    }
    private void MyBaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyBaseForm_Load");
    }
}

public class MyDerivedForm : MyBaseForm
{
    public MyDerivedForm()
    {
        var eventInfo = this.GetType().GetEvent("Load",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var delegateType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(this, 
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, "MyBaseForm_Load", false, true));

        this.Load += MyDerivedForm_Load;
    }

    private void MyDerivedForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyDerivedForm_Load");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! I had the option to change the code at the inherited control since I have the source, but I was curious about how could that be done in a scenario **where that wasn't a possibility**. This rocks.

Comment: If you can change the base class code, it's better to follow the comments which I posted under the question :)